# How to know when hype is reason of a stock prices increase?

Tags: stock-market

I was going to ask if there are any industries or companies that would be insulated from experiencing price changes from hype but I'm assuming it always plays a role.

So, the question then turns to how we can absolutely know a price change was due to anticipated hype?

Perhaps this is due to a product release, incoming CEO, new management, etc.

Does a price change due to hype occur at a certain time when affecting price? Basically does it only occur before the product is released or does it take effect when or after the product is released to confirm the sentiment?

Comment: Are you asking for when a stock price increase is due to hype as opposed to a real value change in the price (which hype could be indicative of)? As opposed to inflation? As opposed to an exogenous market shock in general?

Comment: Probably all of those, I am just focusing on the main drivers of change in a stocks price and was wondering how to determine if a change could be narrowed down to determine how much hype has to do with it.

Answer (score -1):

HypeIndex is using sentiment analysis to tell if the Hype is positive or negative.
https://app.hypeindex.com/
I think that is the best way to know.

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question.